# Error mysql database table, trying to load up

Tags: mysql, steam

Could anyone tell me whats wrong, I'm getting this error when trying to load up the database:

> QL Query failed: INSERT INTO scxpm_statz (uniqueid) VALUES ('STEAM_0:1:406062330') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Obviously, there is no table `scxpm_statz` in the screenshot you've provided. However, what the error you've got?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wrM9pDRL 
 any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set values after `On duplicate key update`

**Example:**

```
INSERT INTO table (id,a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE a=2, b=3, c=4, d=5, e=6, f=7, g=8;
```

Comment: Should use `a=VALUES(a)` to get the value you tried to insert. `a=a` will be a no-op.